# Android App crash with two activity

Tags: java, android

I follow this  [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#ReceiveIntent) and i follow all the steps but when i start the app on my device it says it crashed.So i want to make the MainActivity show first and then if i click a Action bar menu, it will load the second activity (upload.java) ant it will show the upload_layout.I'm training making app for android so i'm not good to program ;)

HERE MY CODE:
    MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.tosseapp.app;

  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.content.res.AssetManager;
  import android.content.res.Resources;
  import android.media.AudioManager;
  import android.media.MediaPlayer;
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.*;
  import java.io.IOException;

  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;

  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   }


     @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void  tosse1(View v)  {
    Button one = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.toxxe);
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Resume the music player

            mp.start();
        }
    });


   }

    public void  tosse2(View v)  {
    Button two = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tozze);
    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Resume the music player

            mp.start();
        }
    });


  }

    public void  tosse3(View v)  {
    Button two = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tossesei);
    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Resume the music player

            mp.start();
        }
    });


    }

     public void  tosse4(View v)  {
      Button two = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button4);
     final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.todde);
    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Resume the music player

            mp.start();
        }
    });


   }

     public void  tosse5(View v)  {
     Button two = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button5);
      final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tossequattro);
      two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Resume the music player

            mp.start();
        }
    });


   }

   public void  tosse6(View v)  {
    Button two = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button6);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tossecinque);
    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Resume the music player

            mp.start();
        }
    });


}
public void upload(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, upload.class);
startActivity(intent);


}
}
```

upload.java:

```
package com.example.tosseapp.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

 public class upload extends ActionBarActivity {

   @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.upload_layout);

   }


   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.upload, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.tosseapp.app" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.tosseapp.app.upload"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.tosseapp.app.MainActivity" />


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

main.xml (menu)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.tosseapp.app.MainActivity" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:onClick="upload"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Can you post the error from your logcat?

Comment: Sorry, what's logcat?

Comment: logcat displays runtime errors, warnings etc

Comment: Where i can view logcat?

Comment: if you are using eclipse with adt plugin then typically it should be at the bottom region of the eclipse window

Comment: no, I use Andorid studio

Comment: Try pressing __Alt-6__.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your `MainActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <application
android:allowBackup="true"

 <!-- other things -->

 <activity
  android:name="com.example.tosseapp.app.MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>

<!-- other activities, services, receivers & close application -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add both your MainActivity and upload.java into your manifest, something like this:

```
<application

    ...

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.tosseapp.app.MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.tosseapp.app.upload"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.tosseapp.app.MainActivity" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.tosseapp.app.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Ok thanks now the app run and show MainActivity for first but when i click it dont show second activity

Comment: What are you clicking on? I glanced at your code and I see you have the function upload( ) that uses an intent and starts upload.java, but the function is never called anywhere else.